# Can't set default value for Address Line 1 (street[0]) on checkout page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I'm a newbie to Magento 2. Trying to set default value for 'street[0]' field of 'shipping-address-fieldset' on the checkout page.

The problem is that values for 'street[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgrMu.png)' and 'street[2]' are set easily, but nothing happens to 'street[0]'

Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
<?php

namespace Sl\SlMagentoCheckout\Plugin\Checkout\Model\Checkout;

class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */

    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ){
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['firstname']['value'] = 'John';

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['lastname']['value'] = 'Doe';


        //Here i added a condition to check the cookie is set with the zipcode and assigned the already set cookie.

        if (isset($_COOKIE['zip_code'])) {

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
            ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['postcode']['value'] = $_COOKIE['zip_code'];

        }

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street'] = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group',
            'label' => __('Address'),
            'required' => true,
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.street',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'sortOrder' => 60,
            'type' => 'group',
            'children' => [
                [
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                    'config' => [
                        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                    ],
                    'dataScope' => '0',
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'validation' => true,
                    'additionalClasses' => 'additional',
                    'visible' => true,
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'value' => 'Adelaide',
                    'label' => __('Street')
                ],
                [
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                    'config' => [
                        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                    ],
                    'dataScope' => '1',
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'validation' => true,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'value' => '999',
                    'label' => __('Number')
                ],
                [
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                    'config' => [
                        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                    ],
                    'dataScope' => '2',
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'validation' => true,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'value' => 'District 1',
                    'label' => __('District')
                ]
            ]

        ];




        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['telephone']['value'] = '094769819117';
        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is working for me https://i.imgur.com/PIu3z6b.jpg In what situation you couldn't see the address?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I haven't found the exact reason yet, but the problem was caused  by the third party delivery method module. After disabling this module the problem disappeared.